# Is there a simple way to fork a file descriptor?

Tags: linux, posix, freebsd, file-descriptor, openbsd

I've just read a handful of man pages: dup, dup2, fcntl, pread/pwrite, mmap, etc.

Currently I am using mmap, but it's not the nicest thing in the world because I have to manage file offset and buffer length myself and basically reimplement read/write in userspace.

From what I gathered:

1. dup, dup2, fcntl just create aliases for the fds, so their offsets and flags are shared - reading from one advances the offset of the others.
2. pread/pwrite can be buggy and give inconsistent results.
3. mmap is buggy on linux when given some uncommon flags, but I don't need them.

Am I missing something or is mmap really the way to go?

(Note that re-`open()`ing a file is dangerous on POSIX - unlike Windows, POSIX provides no guarantees on the path not being moved/deleted while the file is open. On POSIX, you can open a path, move the file, and still read from it. You can even delete the file sometimes. I also couldn't find anything that can open an inode.)

I'd like answers for at least the most common POSIX variants, if there's no one answer for them all.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Processes are forked, not file descriptors. If you want to duplicate your descriptor, use `dup2` or `dup3`. You can also call `childFileHandle = fcntl(..., F_DUPFD, ...)` before forking so the child has a copy of the file descriptor. After copying and forking, the parent would close the child's file descriptor. But I think that's what `dup2` does already.

Comment: `newfd = some_operation(oldfd); assert(oldfd!=newfd); read_some_bytes(oldfd); assert(ftell(oldfd)!=ftell(newfd));` is what I want. "fork" isn't limited to processes: git forks, blockchain forks, etc. the basic idea is that "forks" go separate ways, and I want my forked fds to go separate ways.

Comment: No way, separate offsets <==> different open()s.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, opening `/proc/self/fd/$NUM` will work regardless of whether the file still has the same name it had the first time you opened it, and will generate a new open file description (i.e. a new fd with independent offset and flags).

I don't know of any POSIXly portable way of doing this.

(I also don't know what you mean about pread/pwrite being buggy...)